# Solution of second order linear ODE, $xy''+2y'-y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $xy''+2y'-y=0$.
Could someone point me a direction for research?
Thanks!

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%27%27+%2B+2y%27-y+%3D0) says you get [Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

Comment: Does this help you? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function

Comment: @DMcMor Thanks. I just checked. It looks like it follows "modified bessel functions". Thanks!

Comment: @vitamind I asked it because originally I checked Bessel functions, it looks like their integrals don't converge. However, if we looked at modified Bessel functions, the integral of the formula in wolfram converges.

Comment: Modified Bessel functions are included in the Wikipedia article I linked.